# How to place labels above the inputs in the form?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a reactcomponent and trying to have equal spacing between the 3 controls using rebassjs:

```
<Container>
        <Flex direction={"column"}>
          <Box>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <label>address:</label>
            <input type="text" />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <label>type:</label>
            <select>
              <option>One</option>
            </select>
          </Box>
        </Flex>
</Container>
```

[codesandbox](https://k5q260qy85.codesandbox.io/)

How can I display the labels on top of the controls aligned to the left side of the controls?

Comment: Can't you just add a `<br>` after each label?

Comment: Check this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox